# My app is crashing after launching. the codes on android studio show no error. app installs properly but fails to launch

Tags: android

the app crashes as soon as it launches. The codes show no error, I cant pin point the problem on my logcat. Please help me resolve this I have tried adding Internet & external storage Permission on my AndroidManifest.xml file. Still the same problem

My Logcat shows this error :

> 10-02 12:31:07.830 26511-26511/com.example.e_quickart E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
> 10-02 12:31:11.321 26511-26511/com.example.e_quickart E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.e_quickart, PID: 26511
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 120152256 byte allocation with 4182352 free bytes and 68MB until OOM
> at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:651)
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:486)
> at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1085)
> at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2878)
> at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2767)
> at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
> at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:152)
> at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:140)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:74)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:69)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:199)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:119)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
> at com.example.e_quickart.OnBoardingFragment3.onCreateView(OnBoardingFragment3.java:15)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
> at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
> at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:299)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:259)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19147)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:763)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:426)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:105)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:247)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:117)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1532)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1607)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19147)
> at android

And this is my java File codes :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISFEy.jpg)

Comment: Add below entities in your manifest file android:hardwareAccelerated="false" , android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: It worked Problem Solved Thankx a lot